# Kotlin Annotation Reflection to inject an argument to a function with a custom annotation

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations

I'd love to create a new library for my purposes and am currently struggling with the technical approach needed to fulfill the requirements.

I want to have something like this:

```
class MyFoo {
  @Populate("myText")
  fun giveMeAValue(bar: Bar) {
    LOG.info(bar.message) // "myText"
  }
}
```

I'd like to hook on the function call of `giveMeAValue` or better said I want to hook logic on every function that is annotated with `@Populate`. If a call is being registered I'd like to execute some logic and pass a value for the `bar` parameter. *Please ignore the fact that I might overwrite a value that has been passed already*.

I was reading up for Reflection using Kotling (i.e. https://medium.com/tompee/kotlin-annotation-processor-and-code-generation-58bd7d0d333b) but could not find the thing I'd like to have here.

The hooking/proxy mechanism before the "real" function is being called. That's what I want to achieve.

Can anybody tell me what I am actually looking for? Is there a word for that concept or an article/guide describing this? I was not able to find anything. A code snippet/example would be awesome, too!

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you could explain a bit about the use case you're targeting. What is this to be used for? If you always want the same text passed, why have a parameter at all?  (Or is this to be used with methods inherited from a superclass?)

Comment: The use-case should not be a concern here. I just want to add the argument to a function call. It should work similar to the `@RequestParameter` annotation of Spring MVC if that helps to understand the requirement. `@RequestParameter` is being resolved before the actual function logic is executed and parses a request url by it's `?param=value`. It then adds the value to the parameter expected by the function.

Comment: I think this might help https://medium.com/@gorali/how-mockito-works-7d3a2c77da71#:~:text=Simply%20put%2C%20Mockito%20works%20by,.%2C%20by%20intercepting%20method%20calls.

Comment: @mohsen AOP yes I think that is the thing I was looking for